# Xpath HTML. Возвращает null - C#

Tags: c#, html, xpath

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <i class="_2m_3 _3-91 _8o _8s lfloat _ohe img sp_sJ1LAYlqgzt sx_2abc43"></i>
   <div class="_42ef">
      <div>
         <div class="_50f3">Живет в <a class="profileLink" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81/110970792260960?ref=br_rs" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=110970792260960" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Лос-Анджелес</a>
         </div>
         <span class="_50f8"></span>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно от сюда сохранить "Живёт в" и "Лос-Анджелес". Делаю так, но var text1 и var text2 всегда null. В чём проблема?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HD.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
var text1 = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='_42ef']/div/div[@class='_50f3']/text()");
var text2 = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='_42ef']/div/div[@class='_50f3']/a");
```

Я кажется понял в чём дело. Нужная часть кода находится между тегами `<!-- -->`. Регулярками я сохранил то что записано в тегах и добавил `<!DOCTYPE html>` к началу полученной строки. И всё заработало

Comment: А где первый `div`?

Comment: Не знаю. Вот ссылка с которой я всё получаю https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012438540658&ref=br_rs

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое отступление. Написано по размышлениям над комментариями к ответу.

HTML - не является XML-документом. Поэтому парсить его при помощи XML-парсеров - некорректно. Используйте для этого HTML-парсеры или на крайний случай регулярные выражения.

Можно прочитать весь текст и потом уже с ним работать. Названия классов, как я понимаю, могут поменяться. Да и структура тоже.

```
string content = ...; //текст html 
var reader = new StringReader(content);
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
foreach (XPathNavigator n in nav.Select("div"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.Value);
}
```

Выведет: Живет в Лос-Анджелес

Comment: Если вместо "string.txt" указать переменную с html - System.ArgumentException: "Путь содержит недопустимые знаки." А если создать документ с html: System.Xml.XmlException: "Ошибка при разборе EntityName., строка 3, позиция 1889."

Comment: Прикол в том, что на другой странице другие данные прекрасно читаются моим способом

Comment: убрал из ответа лишнюю работу с файлом

Comment: Всё равно. XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(reader); - System.Xml.XmlException: "Ошибка при разборе EntityName., строка 3, позиция 2927."

Comment: добавил пояснение в начало ответа.

Comment: Так я и использую HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Всё, проблема решена

Comment: да, это моя ошибка. спасибо, что прояснили. теперь понимаю, насколько это полезная библиотека: HtmlAgilityPack